# Cannot sort array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to sort the array alphabetically when the button is pressed but so far everything that I tried failed. The button and function work as I tried console logging something and it prints in the console. I feel like my sorting function is wrong but I'm not sure what to do about it. How can I fix this so it works?

```
import React from "react";
import './Brewery.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ButtonToolbar, DropdownButton, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';


class Brewery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMenu: false,
      breweries: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }

  sortAlpha() {
    const breweries = [].concat(this.state.breweries)
    .sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name)
    this.setState({breweries:breweries});
  }

  render() {

    const { breweries } = this.state;

    return(
     <div className="main-container">
       <div className="banner" styles="background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,101,168,0.6) 0%, rgba(0,36,61,0.6) 50%), url('http://bitterminnesotabrewerytours.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/boston-beer-tours-glass.jpg');">
         <div className="banner-content">
           <h1>Brewery</h1>
           <p>Find the best brewery in town</p>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className="container">
         <div>
           <button onClick={() => this.sortAlpha()}>Sort Alphabetically</button>
         </div>
         <div className="row">
          {breweries.slice(0,10).map((brewery, i) =>
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" key={i}>
              <Link to={`/brewery/${ brewery.id }`}>
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="card-description">
                    <h2>{brewery.brewery_type}</h2>
                    <p>{brewery.city}, {brewery.state}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="card-category"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/20/000000/beer.png"/>  {brewery.name}</div>
                </div>
              </Link>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Brewery;
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `const { breweries } = this.state;` and calling state directly with your map function so instead of `{breweries.slice(0,10).map()` try `this.state.breweries.slice(0, 10).map()`

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
sortAlpha() {
    const breweries = [...this.state.breweries].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
      if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
    this.setState({ breweries: breweries });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not how [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works with strings.

It should return one of three:

- A positive number if `a.value` is greater than `b.value` .
- A negative number if `b.value` is greater than `a.value` .
- Zero (`0`) if `a.value` == `b.value`

So in your case it should be something like this:

```
.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.name < b.name) { return -1; }
  if (a.name > b.name) { return 1; }
  return 0;
});
```

Keep in mind that `sort` is sorting the elements in place (mutation)